# Textbox does not show the normal Google Chrome credit card detection

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

When using Google Chrome, the credit card textbox on my checkout page does not show the normal ability to select an existing credit card. I did set the "auto complete type" as Google recommends.

**Is it due to the long "asp.net" style id field?**

[image]

```
<input name="ctl00$conMain$CheckoutControl1$txtCreditCardNumber" type="text" id="ctl00_conMain_CheckoutControl1_txtCreditCardNumber" title="Credit Card Number " x-autocompletetype="cc-number">
```

https://dia-fundraising-dinner-2015.simpletix.com/Checkout/Guest/Order/df71f52a-f9b9-4dcd-923b-4e2d46bd754a/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine, but you **need** the name on the creditcard as the first input field, chrome uses this to autocomplete the rest. Also use  `autocomplete` besides `x-autocompletetype` as well to support other versions of chrome.

```
<input name="ccname" id="frmNameCC" required 
  placeholder="Full Name" autocomplete="cc-name"> 
<input name="ctl00$conMain$CheckoutControl1$txtCreditCardNumber" 
  type="text" id="ctl00_conMain_CheckoutControl1_txtCreditCardNumber"
  title="Credit Card Number " x-autocompletetype="cc-number" 
  autocomplete="cc-number">
```

See my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c3ck1uxc/1/

Comment: The problem is that most credit card gateways ask for first name and last name as separate fields. All of the google demos have it as a single field with: "cc-name"